# How to read object in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a `formpanel` that has a textfield

```
         {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: name,
            listeners: {
                change: function( field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ){
                    alert(newValue) // [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
                }
            }
         }
```

I using `form.load({...});` to load value to `textfield`

Here is my json

```
{
 "success":true,
  "data":{
          "name":[
                 {"dis":3,"val":0},
                 {"dis":2,"val":1},
                 {"dis":1,"val":2}
           ]
   }
}
```

How can I read `dis` and `val` in `change` function. I `alert(newValue)` look like
`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

**Edit**

1. But I try `alert(newValue[0]);` value is `[`.
2. I print type of `newValue` like `alert(typeof newValue);` result is `string` and I try to convert it to json like

`var json = eval("(" + newValue + ")");`

But I get error

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
([object Object],[object Object],[object Object])
```

Comment: Don't use alert(...) for debugging. It's very inefficient. Use console.log( newValue ) instead. This will print the variable to your debugging console, PLUS it has the benefit of being able to print the full content of an object, not just simple values.

Comment: @existdissolve I using that but still get `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` :(

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense. You're asking how to display an array of objects in a text field.

Comment: @existdissolve I using firefox and see console in firebug.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli b/c I want get value and style that or something else ...

Comment: If you actually want the value of "name" to be usable in a textfield, you'll have to JSON-encode it first

Comment: @existdissolve I try to make a loop to get `dis` and `val` but I can't encode to do that. What do u mean `JSON-encode` ?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Plz see my edit test

Comment: @existdissolve Plz see my edit test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. My json must be look like

```
{
 "success":true,
  "data":{
          "name":[
                 {\"dis\":3,\"val\":0},
                 {\"dis\":2,\"val\":1},
                 {\"dis\":1,\"val\":2}
           ]
   }
}
```

And after that using `Ext.decode(newValue);` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a JSON string into a JavaScript object using the following

`var json = Ext.decode(jsonString);`

Then you can access the members as such:

`console.log(json.success);`